# AEM reverse replication and workflow after that

Tags: java, workflow, replication, aem

I have a requirement to upload the files in publisher and reverse replicate to author and forward replicate to another publisher. After reverse replicating, I need to create a project in AEM author and move the reverse replicated assets to a project-specific location. So I have a custom launcher to call my workflow class(which will create a project and copy the assets to the given location and delete them). This is all fine working.

There is a problem with this, I'm trying to avoid the race condition. The project is created and moves the asset whatever available when the launcher triggers but all the assets haven't reverse replicated yet. Is there a way to wait until the complete reverse replication is complete or any condition to write at the launcher level or some job consumer something. I have a launcher at /content/vendor. I have enough info to create a project after creating data node. But I need all the files to be moved to a project specific location. Appreciate your help. Thanks. Attaching the structure of the files as a screenshot.[image: Jcr structure]

Comment: Reverse replication is no longer recommended by Adobe, what about using another storage?

Comment: you mean s3 or something like that?

Comment: Yes, because of the file submission. But also Adobe provides functionality for user generated content (UGC) using their Storage Resource Provider (SRP): https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/communities/using/accessing-ugc-with-srp.html

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not really like the idea and reverse replication is not always running as stable as it should, here are two ways to deal with your problem:
1. Pack all the files in one zip on publish and reverse replicate the zip file only. You can unpack the whole thing to the correct location on author after reverse replication has been done. In that way there is only one artifact per project.
2. Add a property to the asset's root node on publish. Write an event handler on author that check's for new assets that have your property set. Those assets need to be moved to the project location.

Make sure that you do not move assets while other workflows (DAM Update Asset or others) are executed. This might result in stalled workflow instances or worse.

An alternative way to distribute your assets might be found here:
https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/content-distribution.html

HTH,
Oliver

Comment: There is a 2GB limit on reverse replication. I can't zip and reverse replicate because of size restrictions. I convinced the client only for each file size limit but can't for the whole batch.

Comment: Anyway, I was thinking to create two workflows for creating a project and another for moving them. I think that should solve it but have to try